# YouTube Search Feature Alternative

Tags: youtube, search

YouTube's Advanced Search appears to not be working properly, as I want to do the follow:

- Search within X Channel
- With the search results:

  Related to a,b,c,d keywords
   Return from newest to oldest

I want to then have a link for the page returning the search results just as YouTube does.

Unfortunately, YouTube doesn't accurately do this.

Is there website that has their own search features that can do this?
Could this be done with YouTube API?

Comment: http://gdata-samples-youtube-search-py.appspot.com