# YouTube plus operator is returning results that do NOT contain the keywords

Tags: youtube, search

[YouTube Search Feature Alternative](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/62950/youtube-search-feature-alternative)  seems to indicate I'm not alone. Do this search: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%2Bigaging+%2Bgage+%2Bblocks. click on the first result which is: https://youtu.be/gbsd2OpPOMw, open up the transcript and scroll the transcript up to the top.

Use <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> to search for `igaging`, and nothing is revealed.

I even used Firefox's Web Developer to show the page source and searched it again, and "igaging" is not shown.

[image: result from YouTube search]

Am I doing something incorrect here in my syntax?

Or, are they doing that on purpose?

Or, is this a bug?

### EDIT #1:

In response to [the answer that I should use double quotes](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/106082/14529): I tried that before and did not include it in my original post because, although I got different results, the resulting youtube pages still did not have "igaging" in the content.  For instance: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%22igaging%22+%22gage%22+%22blocks%22 results in the first item listed which is:

[image: search with double quotes]

Clicking on that first item gives https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mlf8EklVarU .

Searching that page does not match any instance of "igaging" at all (including all of the transcript lines), except for the "Up Next" column on the right of the page, the latter of which should *not* be considered in the set being searched:

[image: Up Next screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

**Your syntax is incorrect**, if you want a specific term you must use **quotation marks** e.g. "igaging"

Comment: I thought that too, but that does not give pages that have "igaging" in it either (well, I only tested one). See my EDIT #1 in the question.

Comment: It works best with 2 keyboards only or two things inside the auotation works if you try "igaging" + "gaging" or "gaging" + "blocks" or "igaging" + "blocks" it will work, but with more than two terms it tends to ignore the one with the fewest results

Comment: Why would they design it in such a way to ignore terms? If it comes back with no results, that is actually good. But what I don't want to do is have to do a brute force search through all search results, using CTRL-f, which defeats the whole purpose of using their web-based interface.